# How to use call_user_func with params?

Tags: arrays, function, callback

I never thought to run into that problem but I can't find a way alone here.

I have a mapper array with keys that shall(or call) be functions.
But I got all the time that error:

> call_user_func() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback

```
class Myclass
{
  protected static $_mapper = array(
        'setFuncA' => 'somethingWithA',
        'setFuncB' => 'somethingWithB'
    );

    public function getData() {
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

       // $params looks like
       // array('somethingWithA' => 'someValue')

        foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
            if (in_array($key, self::$_mapper)) {
                call_user_func(key(self::$_mapper), $params); // e.g. call_user_func('setFuncA', 'somethingWithA')
            }
        }
        // do something;
    }

    public function somethingWithA($args) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

What am I missing here? I tried it also with call_user_func_array() but got also an error.

**Solved**
Ok found my problem.
I had to call

```
call_user_func(array($this, key(self::$_mapper)), $params);
```

This finally works.
But I still have no clue why I have to add "$this" and encapsulate it with an array.

Comment: Try to create a function with a return `return key(self::$_mapper);`

Comment: `call_user_func` will not check whether it is called from within a class method or not. So you'll have to provide the context. That's why you need to add `$this` within an array. Have a look at the [manual](https://php.net/manual/language.types.callable.php) for callables.

Comment: "But I still have no clue why I have to add "$this" and encapsulate it with an array." - Interpreter don't know on which object should do call given method.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Myclass
{
  protected static $_mapper = array(
        'setFuncA' => 'somethingWithA',
        'setFuncB' => 'somethingWithB'
    );

    public function getData() {
        $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();

       // $params looks like
       // array('somethingWithA' => 'someValue')

        foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
            if (in_array($key, self::$_mapper)) {
                call_user_func_array('myExtraFunc', $params);
            }
        }
        // do something;
    }

    public function somethingWithA($args) {
        // do something
    }

    public static function myExtraFunc() {
         return key(self::$_mapper);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Djaman, but it returns the same error message when I debugg that line.